# Make tab visible in shiny after analysis is complete

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where a relatively lengthy analysis is performed on the server. I would like to have a couple of tabs to allow the user to view and download the output from the analysis. These tabs should only be visible once the analysis has been completed.

There's an [example here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/43) of hiding a tab until an event (button click in this case), but I haven't been able to figure out making the event the completion of the analysis.

In the minimal example below, I've adapted the example - the tab is still made visible following the button click.

How do I make it so that tab2" only becomes visible once the loop is complete?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(
    "move/view tabs after analysis",
    id = "navbar",
    tabPanel(
      title = "Start",
      actionButton("button", "Run Analysis")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "Analysis output",
      value = "tab2",
      tableOutput("tableOutput")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=tab2]")
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$tableOutput <- renderTable({

      withProgress(message = 'Working', {
        for(i in 1:5) {
          incProgress(1/5)
          Sys.sleep(2)
        }
      })  
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=tab2]")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does the trick.  This works by first definiing the table output properly on the outside, rather than inside an observe statement, but having it return NULL until the button has been clicked.  If the button is clicked, it does the long-running calculation and only afterwards does it unhide the tab.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(
    "move/view tabs after analysis",
    id = "navbar",
    tabPanel(
      title = "Start",
      actionButton("button", "Run Analysis")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "Analysis output",
      value = "tab2",
      tableOutput("tableOutput")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=tab2]")
  })

  output$tableOutput <- renderTable({
    if(input$button > 0){
      withProgress(message = 'Working', {
        for(i in 1:5) {
          incProgress(1/5)
          Sys.sleep(2)
        }
      })
      toggle(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=tab2]")
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })
  outputOptions(output,"tableOutput", suspendWhenHidden=F)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great, that does the job